# Cannot find out the triangle's area in cpp

Tags: c++

In the following block of code when I try to print the triangle's area why am I always getting the answer to be 1. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. You might want to copy-paste this code into your system.

I want to calculate the area of rectangle and triangle by inheriting them as derived classes from the base class shape. I have tried to use a switch case to create a neat menu. But for some reason, whenever I try to calculate the area of the triangle it always gives me the value to be 1. I can't figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help?

```
/**
 * @file L6W9.cpp
 * @author calculates area using base class and virtual funcitons 
 * @brief 
 * @version 0.1
 * @date 2022-03-16
 * 
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2022
 * 
 */
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class shape{
    public: 
    double side_one; 
    double side_two; 
    shape(){}
    shape(double a, double b ){
        side_one = a; 
        side_two = b;
    } 
    void set_data(double x, double y)
    {
        side_one = x; 
        side_two = y; 
    }
    
    virtual void display_area(){
            
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"Side one: "<<side_one<<endl<<"Side two: "<<side_two<<endl;
    }
};
class triangle: public shape{
     
    public: 
    double side_three; 
    triangle(){}

    void set_data(double x, double y ,double z ){
        shape:: set_data(x,y);
        side_three = z; 

    }
    void display_area(){
        double  s = (side_one+ side_two + side_three)/2; 
        double x = s*(s-side_one)*(s-side_two)*(s-side_three);
        double triangle_area = pow(s*x,1/2); 
        cout<<"The area of the triangle is: "<<triangle_area<<" "<<"squared units"<<endl;  

    }
    void display(){
        
        cout<<"Length of first side : "<<side_one<<"units"<<endl;
        cout<<"Length of second side : "<<side_two<<"units"<<endl; 
        cout<<"Length of third side : "<<side_three<<"units"<<endl;
    }
    

};

class rectangle : public shape{
    public:
    rectangle(){}
    void display_area()
    {
        double rect_area = side_one *side_two; // length*breadth 
        cout<<"The area of the rectangle is: "<<rect_area <<" "<<"sqaured units"<<endl<<endl; 

    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"Length of the rectangle is: "<<side_one<<" "<<"units"<<endl;
        cout<<"Breadth of the rectangle is "<<side_two<<" "<<"units"<<endl;
    }
};
void menu(){
    cout<<"**********************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"Choose betweeen rectangle and triangle"<<endl;
    cout<<"Rectangle: 1"<<endl;
    cout<<"Trianlge: 2"<<endl;
    cout<<"Quit: 0 "<<endl;
    cout<<"***********************************************"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    
    rectangle r1; 
    triangle t1;  
    int choice; 
    do{
        menu(); 
        cin>>choice; 

        switch(choice){
            case  0 : 
                break; 
            case 1: 
                cout<<"You have chosen: Rectangle"<<endl;
                double a, b; 
                cout<<"Lenght: "; 
                cin>>a; 
                cout<<"Breadth: "; 
                cin>>b; 
                r1.set_data(a,b); 
                r1.display(); 
                r1.display_area();
                break; 
            case 2: 
                cout<<"You have chosen: Triangle"<<endl;
                double c,d,e; 
                cout<<"Side one: "; 
                cin>>c; 
                cout<<"Side two: "; 
                cin>>d; 
                cout<<"Side three: "; 
                cin>>e; 
                t1.set_data(c,d,e); 
                t1.display(); 
                t1.display_area();
                break; 
            default: 
                cout<<"Invalid Output"<<endl; 
                break; 
                
        }
        
    }
    while (choice!=0); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There's a ton of code here, is all of it really necessary to understand your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use

```
double triangle_area = pow(s*x,1/2);
```

`1/2` in C++ gives `0` because it performs integer division.

But even if you used `0.5`, you don't want a `pow` there. You want:

```
double triangle_area = std::sqrt(s*x);
```

`sqrt` is specialized for square root. Use it :-)